# ErrorName is not defined in terminal

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial and this is the code I did in hello.py

```
name = input('enter name: ')

print('my name is ' + name)
```

above code gave me below error

```
enter name: cc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input('enter name: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cc' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code in the question, please? The above code should work fine without any errors

Comment: @Sashaank OP is using Python 2.

Comment: sigh, it worked when I changed to python3 to my vscode.